# How can I limit the number of curl calls to the write function?

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

I'm trying to limit the number of times this WRITEFUNCTION is called. Is there any way I can do that?

defining the writefunction:

```
conn.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, on_receive)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's a very bizarre thing to try to do.

Comment: Where does it write to? Is it sending to server or receiving? In the general case, try to fool it by passing a StringIO object or passing your own function there to hold data in memory. Post the relevant code (at least that function's definition and the code that calls it) and we can help further.

Comment: My issue is that this function is called whenever new data is available, but I need it to stop after it is called 10 times. Do you think there is a way to do this?

Comment: Here's the code: http://www.pressalive.com/twitters-real-time-stream-api-python/twitter/2010/11/28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a dirty simple version that should work. Building PycURL to test and find a better way.

```
import pycurl, json

STREAM_URL = "http://chirpstream.twitter.com/2b/user.json"

USER = "segphault"
PASS = "XXXXXXXXX"

class LimitError(Exception): pass

counter = 0
limit = 10
def on_receive(data):
    global counter
    if counter < 10:
        print data
        counter += 1
    else:
        raise LimitError    
conn = pycurl.Curl()
conn.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, "%s:%s" % (USER, PASS))
conn.setopt(pycurl.URL, STREAM_URL)
conn.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, on_receive)

try:
    conn.perform()
    print "Exited Normally"
except LimitError:
    print "Reached limit, exiting"
except pycurl.error:
    if counter == limit:
        print "pycurl expected error, nothing to worry about"
    else:
        raise
finally:
    conn.close()

print "All done"
```

Comment: The bad news is that I didn't find any better way so far, will look more later.

Comment: Is there an alternative to the sys.exit() command so that it doesn't quit out of my django server? Forgot to mention that I'm running this in a django view - sorry.

Comment: This new version should work nicely without the sys.exit. You might still see traceback info, I think that's because the exception comes from another thread (so it shows even if handled later), but if you get to the "All done" line everything is working fine.